# Null Reference when trying to assign a value from a map

Tags: apex

```
    set<Id> acctIDs = new Set<Id>();
for (Opportunity newOpp : newOpps) {
    acctIDs.add(newOpp.Install_At__c); 
    acctIDs.add(newOpp.AccountId); 
}
Map<Id, Account> accMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Region__c, System_AM__r.name
                                                FROM Account
                                                WHERE Id 
                                                IN : acctIDs]);

       if(accMap != null){
        if(accMap.get(newOpp.Install_At__c).Region__c != null)newOpp.Install_at_Region__c = accMap.get(neOpp.Install_At__c).Region__c;
        if(accMap.get(newOpp.Install_At__c).System_AM__r.name != null)newOpp.System_AM__c = accMap.get(newOpp.Install_At__c).System_AM__r.name;
       }
      System.debug('accMap' + string.ValueOf(accMap));
```

I know that's a lot of null checks...because no matter what I do I get the Null reference error. What am I missing?

Maybe a `accMap.containskey(acctIDs) != null` or `accMap.get(newOpp.Install_At__c) != null` ?

Answer (score 1):

First, `accMap` is not null. We know this because you initialized it using the `new` keyword just a few lines earlier. Anytime you use `new` you always get a new object<sup>1</sup>. You can safely skip this check:

```
if(accMap != null){
```

Second, `accMap.get(newOpp.Install_At__c)` could be null. If Install_At__c is a lookup field, this should only ever be null if newOpp.Install_At__c is also null. You could use one of the two following forms to avoid null values.

```
// if newOpp.Install_At__c is a lookup field, we can use:
if(newOpp.Install_At__c != null) {
// For other types, we'd check the return value from the map:
if(accMap.get(newOpp.Install_At__c) != null) {
```

Third, strictly speaking, if the above is not null, you don't need to check for any other nulls. As such, you can just assign the value.

Fourth, you may want to assign a null value to the fields you're trying to populate to begin with, otherwise they'll be "out of sync" with the data you're copying from.

So, your final code should probably look something like this:

```
// Previous code omitted
Map<Id, Account> accMap = new Map<Id, Account>(
  [SELECT Id, Region__c, System_AM__r.name 
   FROM Account
   WHERE Id IN : acctIDs]);
Account accRecord = accMap.get(newOpp.Install_At__c);
if(accRecord != null) {
  newOpp.Install_at_Region__c = accRecord.Region__c;
  newOpp.System_AM__c = accRecord.System_AM__r.name;
} else {
  newOpp.Install_At_Region__c = newOpp.System_AM__c = null;
}
```

---

*<sup>1</sup>If you don't get a new object, you get an Exception. Thus, this is true for practically all cases. If for some reason you had concern about a catchable exception, then you'd have to worry about potentially null objects.*

Comment: sfdcfox you're a god send, do you have a  patreon. So yes the Install_At__c is a lookup field. But wouldn't doing Account accRecord = accMap.get(newOpp.Install_At__c); then doing a null check on accRecord be the same as if(accMap.get(newOpp.Install_At__c) !=null); So wouldn't i want to skip skip creating the accRecord and just do a null check on newOpp.Install_At__c ?

Comment: @faceUntoKeyboard I have a Patreon, but I never set it up for public use. I might get to it some day, when I get back to blogging regularly. In the meantime, to directly answer your followup, yes, you could check the field for null directly, it would be marginally more CPU efficient to do so, and probably make your code more self-documenting. I wrote the answer originally without assuming the field was really a lookup field and could potentially have invalid values in it; knowing this, checking the field for null directly would be ideal.